# android mediaplayer only plays some files on android 2.3

Tags: android, media-player

I am making an app, which need to display some videos i download from a server. However, some of the videos just gives an error on Gingerbread, while working fine on Jelly Bean.

```
File f = new File(file);
// Tried to set source with the absolute path (file)
mPlayer.setDataSource(ParcelFileDescriptor.open(f, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY).getFileDescriptor());
// holder is the surfaceholder for the SurfaceView
mPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
mPlayer.prepare();
```

I have testet the videos on an elder Samsung, Emulator and an elder Sony Ericsson. Some of the phones could play a video the others couldn't.

I recieved the videos in Quicktime format (.mov) and used

```
ffmpeg -i file.mov -vcodec copy -acodec copy file.mp4
```

on all the videos to get MPEG-4 which android should understand. This is why it is confusing that some of the videos works while others don't.

The videos are downloaded to

```
context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath() + "/path/to/videos/";
```

and i check the sha1sum to verify the download went good.

The errors i get varies.

I get MediaPlayer error (1, -2147483648) on the emulator and MediaPlayer error (1, -15) on the Samsung device.

So how do i get the videos to play?

Comment: MediaPlayer error (1, -2147483648)　usually means illegal format

Comment: The solution was to scale the videos. Having a 1080p video on a 240p screen wasn't anything android could handle. That also counts for 4.0.4